# PyQGIS/QGIS 2.18: Filter layers by name in QgsMapLayerComboBox

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, filter, qgis-2.18

I need a QgsMapLayerComboBox to show only layers whose name contains a specific word. 
I have no way to know the names or geometry of the layers beforehand - I can only filter them based on whether or not they contain this word.

I thought about using `setFilters()`, but it looks like it only allows to filter by geometry or layer type, not by layer name. I also read about `setExceptedLayerList()` - but as I mentionned earlier, I don't know the exact name of the layers I don't want to show in the QgsMapLayerComboBox.

So, is there a way for me to use `setExceptedLayerList()` with an expression referring to layers whose name does *not* contain the word I need? Or another method that would allow me to filter the layers in my QgsMapLayerComboBox based on a word in their names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following logic which excludes the layers not containing the name you define:

```
name = 'someName'
layer_list = []

for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if name not in layer.name().lower():
        layer_list.append(layer)

self.dockwidget.mMapLayerComboBox.setExceptedLayerList(layer_list)
```

If you want it to be case-sensitive, remove the `.lower()` method.